# Generating backslash in a string in PHP

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, string, backslash

I have the following string that the ultimate goal is to use it in like sql. The output should be `'%"cardSelected":"120-B-110-C"%'` .

But the output of this string is generating with backslashes like this below
 `'%\"cardSelected\":\"120-B-110-C\"%'`

```
$search_term = '"cardSelected":"120-B-110-C"';
$like =  '%'. $search_term .'%';
        
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
       "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = %s AND post_content LIKE %s;",
       'publish',
       $like,
);
```

I tried using str_replace as below, but the slashes were not removed either

```
$search_term = '"cardSelected":"120-B-110-C"';
$like =  str_replace('\\','','%'. $search_term .'%');
```

Comment: _“I tried using str_replace as below, but the slashes were not removed either”_ - there aren’t any to begin with, in the content of your variable `$search_term`. This escaping is done by `$wpdb->prepare`.